# Auto expanding input box without disturbing other blocks

Tags: jquery, html, css

As title

Fiddle in here ---> http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/2943/

```
$('#box').focus(function() {
    /*to make this flexible, I'm storing the current width in an attribute*/
    $(this).attr('data-default', $(this).height());
    $(this).animate({
        height: 150
    }, 'slow');
}).blur(function() {
    /* lookup the original width */
    var w = $(this).attr('data-default');
    $(this).animate({
        height: w
    }, 'slow');
});
```

My idea here is that, based on the fiddle, whenever user clicks on the input, the input will auto-increase its height to make it look like a textarea kind of input, but at the same time not pushing the text under the input downward.

I tried with adding z-index to the input when on focus but didn't work. The text still got pushed downward when the input expands. I want it so that when the input expands, it will look as if the input overlaps the text.

So how can i achieve this? Or is there any plugin that performs similar thing as my idea above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your Fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/2948/

HTML:

```
<div style = "position:relative;" id="textboxwrapper" onload="textboxload()">
  <textarea type="text" id="box" style="width: 100px; position:absolute; z-index: 100; height:20px; resize: none;"></textarea>
</div>

<div>This is just a test</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#textboxwrapper').css('height', $('#box').height());
});

$('#box').focus(function()
{
  /*to make this flexible, I'm storing the current width in an attribute*/
  $(this).attr('data-default', $(this).height());
  $(this).animate({ height: 150 }, 'slow');
}).blur(function()
{
  /* lookup the original width */
  var w = $(this).attr('data-default');
  $(this).animate({ height: w }, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: It works. But then when it expands, it still behave as a text input. How do i make it so that it behave as a textarea when expands, and text input when on normal.

Comment: you need to make it a textarea with a small initial width so it looks like an input and then just change its height when it expands. i have updated the answer.